# Unclickable listview entry with two textviews

Tags: android

I have a listview containing some headers to separate the list items. The idea is to make it behave similarly to the contacts app in jellybean with the section headers for letter initials. The approach i am using to do this is to have an extra textview in my list_item.xml that i dynamically hide or show based on whether a new divider is needed for the next letter.

The issue is, whenever a section header is added, it is clickable along with the very next client entry. So it would be like

```
A
_____
Ally
```

THis entire list cell would be selectable by the user. I would like just the Ally to be selected and the header to be unselectable. How can i do this?

Comment: Another approach you may want to consider is to use a list of views, each of which contains a header and a list of items (e.g. each view in the outside list would be the letter and then a list of contacts). I'm unsure of the technical details of having the outer list ignore click events and the inner lists listen for them, however.

Comment: How are you adding the headers?

Comment: They are always defined in my list_item.xml but they are just toggled between visible and gone depending on whether i need them

Comment: So doesn't using `android:clickable="false"` or `android:focusable="false"` work on those `TextViews`?

Comment: I have tried both, but they do nothing

Comment: If the list_item itself is unclickable, can you make individual views inside it clickable?

Comment: @Michelle The list_item is clickable, the individual views inside i cannot seem to pick and choose which to make clickable using the xml tags suggested above.

Comment: Are you able to do so if you set clickable to false on the list_item, or does that prevent the item and all of its contents from being clicked? It's been a while since I've dealt with this kind of thing.

Comment: @Michelle I can disable the list_item in the adapter when i return from getView and yes, it disables the entire content.

Comment: I'd take a look at the following https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you are trying to achieve:
http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/05/pinned-header-listview-as-in-contacts.html

The custom `PinnedHeaderListView` can be downloaded from [here](https://code.google.com/p/devoxx2010/source/browse/trunk/devoxx-schedule/src/net/peterkuterna/android/apps/devoxxsched/ui/widget/PinnedHeaderListView.java) (it's the Devoxx 2010 Schedule app he writes about in the blog)

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1, you can use the [Amazing List View Library](https://github.com/will-districtnerds/mingle-amazinglistview).this worked around for me. you can refer to it's code which is not very long.

Solution 2, add a header in the normal listview as following:

itemheader.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/daily_title"
          android:textColor="#545454"
          android:text="04/16"
          android:paddingLeft="10dp"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:textSize="10sp"
          android:id="@+id/header"/>
```

item_rows.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              style="@style/ArticleList.item"
              android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            layout="@layout/itemheader" />
```

then you just need to take care which row need to show the header.

Comment: If you wanted a solution that does not require an external library, solution 2 is probably the best one.  In the same logic where you would choose whether or not to show the header, just replace that with choosing whether or not to inflate the different views.

Answer (score 1):

A way to implement this is to use a custom `ArrayAdapter` that implements [SectionIndexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html).
A nice and simple tutorial can be found here:

http://twistbyte.com/tutorial/android-listview-with-fast-scroll-and-section-index

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I see the problem.

You already have a setup like this:

> A
>   **_** Ally
>
> - A click on "A" (or the area right of it) should not trigger the ListView's "onItemClick" event.
> - A click on "Ally" (or the area right of it) should trigger the ListView's "onItemClick" event.

There is an easy fix for this:

The click on "A" has to be consumed. I suppose you have a setup similar to the following inside your `SomeAdapter.getView()` method:

```
if (someCondition) {
    headerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    headerTextView.setText("Hello");
} else {
    headerTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Since `headerTextView` does not have an `OnClickListener` set to it, the click event is passed on to the ListView's `OnItemClickListener`. To stop this from happening, add an OnClickListener to `headerTextView` when you set its visibility to `VISIBLE`.

```
if (someCondition) {
    headerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    headerTextView.setText("Hello");

    headerTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Header", "TextView Header was clicked");
        }
    });
} else {
    headerTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

For your objective, you can leave `onClick(View v)` with an empty body.

Caution: The header (given in your example) is one character long. You will need to give the TextView (holding the header) `layout_width` of `match_parent`. This way, it's appearance will not be affected, but the visible (empty) area to the right of the text will be filled by `headerTextView`. A click within this area will not trigger ListView's `onItemClick()`. And, a click on "Ally" or elsewhere will trigger it.